# Problem with join query

Tags: mysql

I have two tables tracklist and song. I am fetching all values from song having sid as primary and tracklist having sid as foreign. Though fetching all values from song using this query is successfull.

```
SELECT t.sid as tsid, s.sid as ssid, s.name from song s LEFT JOIN tracklist t ON s.sid=t.sid;
```

But If I wish to fetch those values from song that are not in tracklist this query is not fetching single row.

```
SELECT t.sid as tsid, s.sid as ssid, s.name from song s LEFT JOIN tracklist t ON s.sid=t.sid where t.sid= NULL;
```

Comment: Have you tried using a `JOIN` or a `INNER JOIN` instead of a `LEFT JOIN`?

Comment: I don't know why your second query is failing (it looks ok to me) but I'd use an inner join for the first query.

Comment: @JMichel no it's legitimate to use a left join to find rows not in a table. The mysql doc even [mentions it](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/left-join-optimization.html): "If you use LEFT JOIN to find rows that do not exist in some table ..."

Comment: For the second query, try using `tsid` instead of `t.sid` in the WHERE clause

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than `=NULL`, use `IS NULL`:

```
SELECT t.sid as tsid, s.sid as ssid, s.name from song s LEFT JOIN tracklist t ON s.sid=t.sid where t.sid IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to use `IS NULL` not `= NULL`

e.g:

```
SELECT t.sid as tsid, s.sid as ssid, s.name 
FROM song s 
LEFT JOIN tracklist t ON s.sid=t.sid 
WHERE t.sid IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.sid as tsid, s.sid as ssid, s.name from song s LEFT JOIN tracklist t ON s.sid<>t.sid;
```

its checking if the id of s.sid is null. if you didn't give the id then its not going to return it.

`<>` means not equal...

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
SELECT t.sid as tsid, s.sid as ssid, s.name 
from song s LEFT OUTER JOIN tracklist t ON s.sid=t.sid where t.sid IS NULL;
```

Comment: `LEFT OUTER JOIN` is just another way of using `LEFT JOIN`. Some language use one, some the other, not both.

Comment: I use (+) myself in oracle, LEFT JOIN/INNER JOIN ... terminology always confuses me. Thanks for the correction. The idea is to select everything from song but only tracklist which are null